# Does Java's "Class.forName" scan all class names from all jars?

Tags: java, class, jar, driver, loader

On compile or run, we usually have a lot of class/jar dependencies, and the database driver's jar is just one of them. So, does

```
Class.forName(X)
```

have to scan all these .class/.jar file names to locate proper driver class named X? If not, does `Class.forName` has any rule/algorithm to find particular class?

Comment: It will look for the class through all folders/archives on the classpath. Why thequestion? BTW, it still looks for classes in the same places even when it encounters class references by executing code normally.

Comment: Check this : https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Fortify-User-Discussions/How-to-include-jar-files-in-a-scan-project/td-p/1546330 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It delegates to the `ClassLoader` of the calling class. In most cases the answer is yes but there are `ClassLoader` implementations with more sophisticated rules e.g. [OSGI which uses dynamic modules](https://www.osgi.org/) or [JEE Server Application Classloading](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/programming/classloading.html).

```
public static Class<?> forName(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
  Class<?> caller = Reflection.getCallerClass();
  return forName0(className, true, ClassLoader.getClassLoader(caller), caller);
}
```